# Apologetics != Offtopic

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Or for you Pascal programmers "Apologetics <> Offtopic"...

That's the case isn't it?  I can only see the rationale for closing [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60718/how-can-i-defend-my-position-of-being-against-homosexuality-in-front-of-unbeliev) is that the OP didn't specify what kinds of answers he or she wanted.

That's a problem, so when I answer with a Catholic answer and 4Castle answers with a JW comment we both do something technically incorrect for the site.

### HOWEVER

Apologetics  is "reason applied to faith".  Reason, which should be accessible to anyone regardless of their faith.

But, but, but, isn't this a "TRUTH QUESTION?", that's true - if you think that "what is reasonable?" is the same question as "what is truth?".  But since those aren't the same thing :

**I answer that**

Answers that sound reasonable to questions on practical, "how do I be a Christian in the modern world" type questions are topical rather an off-topic.

They ought to be scoped appropriately (if necessary, although the reason for opposition to homosexual behavior and lifestyle doesn't deviate greatly between Christian sects that do oppose it), they should not be too broad (as this question probably is, which is the close reason incidentally)

### On the Other Hand

Isn't this Pastoral Advice? Shouldn't you be asking your pastor how to deal with something, what is appropriate, etc?

**I answer** 
Not necessarily, when you're asking about how to deal with a "Big Hypothetical Subject" that's different than when asking a question about a "Little Niggling Thing" and I think the broadness of the question offsets the pastoral adviceness of the question.

Still, it has at least 1 and a half strikes against it, which I think justifies it being on hold - but not permanently.

Comment: If it was changed to something less personal sounding, I'd vtr. Something like "what are common approaches to justify opposition to homosexuality to non-believers?" This keeps it objective and elicits citations and sources.

Comment: This looks like the typical question on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/, which I cringe to think we'd allow here.

Answer (score 2):

[***"...what to say if I'm asked why I stand against homosexuality."***](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60718/how-can-i-defend-my-position-of-being-against-homosexuality-in-front-of-unbeliev)

> > "Apologetics is 'reason applied to faith'. Reason, which should be accessible to anyone regardless of their faith (OP.")
> >
> > ["The only reason I have at the moment is that the Bible is against homosexuality."](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60718/how-can-i-defend-my-position-of-being-against-homosexuality-in-front-of-unbeliev)

Given proper direction from CH.SE community (comments, edits, inviting demeanor...), this question could have been rescued from suspicion, with respect to, *Pastoral advice/Truth Question*.

I, myself, am more disposed toward answering **to**, the *passion/importance* of a question, than I am toward answering from the safety of site guidelines; there is more than a little challenge with interpretation there.

However, given the constraints, this question could be reinterpreted (recast, since you like to use pseudo code in some of your comments).

The question could easily have been stated:

> 'I am a *[denomination here]*. 'I have recently come to the conclusion that I need to make a biblical argument for *[denomination here]*'s position on the topic of homosexuality. What is the scriptural position that establishes *our* doctrine on this subject.'

Simply a prototype, of course, but there is nothing in a question of 'this type' that should cause anyone to wonder.

I admit, I am still trying to sift a real question out of this post. I see that you declared a pointer to one upon entry, but I never see it initialized. I do appreciate the observation, all the same.